# Conditional Probability (intuition-related question)

Tags: probability

I'm having trouble gaining intuition as to why the answer is 2/3 as opposed to 1/2.

Here is the question:

Alice has five coins in a bag: two coins are normal, two are double-headed, and the last one is double-tailed. She reaches into the bag and randomly pulls out a coin. The coin lands and shows heads face-up. What is the probability that the face-down side is heads?

So our sample space starts off as `{H,T  H,T   H,H   H,H   T,T}`
Given that face-up is `{H}` our probability will be conditioned on the event

`{H,T  H,T   H,H   H,H }`occurs, which leaves these possibilities -> `{H, H, T, T}`. 
Intuitively speaking, shouldn't the answer be 2/4?

The answer uses law of total probability to get the answer, which makes sense mathematically, but I don't get what's wrong with my logic in the intuitive answer.

Thank you.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916522/a-man-has-5-coins-in-his-pocket).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are of course correct that it can only be one of the four coins as indicated, but when you say that the sample space $HT, HT, HH, HH$ leaves as options $T,T,H,H$ you are effectivly assuming that of the double-headed coins, you  could only have gotten the 'first' head being face-up. But since the 'second' one could be the one that's face-up as well, your possible outcomes for the face-down side are $T,T,H,H,H,H$

Comment: Thank  you. This makes sense. I wrote this in another comment, but essentially, "I was assuming that since {H} has already occurred our sample space gets reduced to {T, T, H, H}. But since there are more heads in the original sample space, we have a higher chance of a double-headed coin being chosen, which is something I didn't look into.

Comment: @moondra Yes, that's it! :)

Answer (score 1):

"Intuitive thinking doesn't always give the right answer." is the short answer.

> `{H,T  H,T   H,H   H,H }`occurs, which leaves these possibilities -> `{H, H, T, T}`

First off I'm not sure what you mean here, but I think something like "Head means we can ignore the double-tailed coin. Then we could have head in two cases and tails in two cases." Your intuitive is wrong simply because in `{H,T  H,T   H,H   H,H }` the `H` occurs six times but the `T` occurs only twice. There is no reduction to `{H, H, T, T}` I could see.

Comment: I was assuming that since `{H}` has already occurred our sample space gets reduced to `{T, T, H, H}`. But since there are more heads in the original sample space, we have a higher chance of a double-headed coin being chosen. I think that's what I didn't look into.

Answer (score 1):

The sample space is:
$$S=\{HT,HT,H_1H_2,H_2H_1,H_1H_2,H_2H_1\},$$
where the first (second) is top (bottom) and the index numbers are sides.

Hence:
$$P=\frac{n(\text{bottom is head})}{total}=\frac46.$$

Answer (score 0):

Our configuration space is
\begin{eqnarray*}
\{H,T \,\,\, H,T \,\,\, H_1,H_2 \,\,\, H_1,H_2 \,\,\, T_1,T_2 \}.
\end{eqnarray*}
There are $6$ possible ways to get a head
\begin{eqnarray*}
\{\color{red}{H},T  \,\,\, \color{red}{H},T  \,\,\, \color{red}{H_1},H_2 \,\,\,  \color{red}{H_1},H_2  \,\,\, \color{red}{H_2},H_1  \,\,\, \color{red}{H_2},H_1 \}.
\end{eqnarray*}
So ...